# Windows Service Write output to file

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, output

I have the following batch script:

```
echo %time% >> C:\file.txt
C:\MyProgram\program.exe /arg1 >> C:\file.txt
echo ------- >> C:\file.txt
```

I have created a service with

```
sc create ProgramRun type= own start= auto binPath= "cmd /c cd /d c:\MyProgram\ && start script.bat"
```

After a reboot, in `file.txt` I have printed the correct time, but without my program ouput. In that program, I have some simple `printf`

What can I do to write the output to a file without editing the program?

Comment: I suppose your program was not executed at all as the batch file was executed as service. Use `"C:\MyProgram\program.exe"` if the path to your program contains a space anywhere. Or your program writes the messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout` and therefore you need additionally `2>>C:\file.txt`. And why do you not start the batch file as service directly instead of `cmd /c cd /d c:\MyProgram\ && start script.bat`?

Answer (score 1):

As a Windows Service, your program is being run in the context of the Local System account, which may not have the rights necessary to launch and run your program properly. Try editing the service and [setting the Log On credentials](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) to a Windows account that you know can execute your program properly.

Also, while the Windows Service Control Manager (SCM) will happily start your batch file, the outcome reported will always be failure, specifically **"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"**. This is because your batch file can not communicate with the SCM! Have a look at Microsoft's free (and basic) [Srvany "service wrapper"](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) to avoid this problem.